# Running automatic annotation in cvat with tensorflow results in status code 400 "No labels found for tf annotation"

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run a tensorflow for pre-annotation in cvat.
I can start the docker container, option in the menue shows up. 
However, after selection of the model i get the error:

```
Could not infer model for the task 10
Error: Request failed with status code 400. "No labels found for tf annotation".
```

It seems that i need to specify some labels, in which format do i have to configure them though ?
Documentation seems sparse on this one. Maybe someone on here knows something?
Also if some stackoverflow wizzard with a lot of reputation could create the tag cvat i would be very happy :)